# How to draw shapes on image in a UIScrollView without hindering zoom and scoll?

Tags: ios, touch, zooming, uigesturerecognizer, drawrect

I have a UIScrollView containing an image that I can zoom in on and pan/scroll around. I would like to draw shapes on this image so I can call attention to certain portions of it. I've currently done this with UIViews by drawing the shapes in `drawRect`.

The problem is this: say I draw a shape around nearly the entire image, or say I draw numerous shapes that overlap and take up almost the entire image. Now, I can no longer zoom or pan/scroll because the UIViews are overlapping the image and keeping the touch events from occurring.

[image: Example]

See the image for an example. The yellow circle would be relatively harmless if I did nothing, because it doesn't take up much of the image. Only touches in that circle would be a problem. However, the red square is definitely a problem. That UIView clearly overlaps most of the scroll view, which means I won't get touch events on the image in the scroll view.

I am currently adding touch events to the UIImageView that is the main content of the scroll view. I could do the same for every subview (shape) that I add, but this would get really complicated if I had to determine that 1 touch on one shape plus 1 touch on another shape should be handled like a 2 touch event on the UIImageView so I can force zooming with a pinch gesture. But that seems like overkill (and I don't know how I would do that).

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the property `userInteractionsEnabled` to NO on the views that you use to draw your shapes should make the trick: views that you cannot interact with are ignored for touch events.

Comment: Ah, didn't even think about that. So disabling user interaction will essentially all the touch "through" those views? If so, this is exactly what I needed. I'll try later today and get back to you. Thanks for the help.